# Worksheet Looping Not Skipping Desired Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to have a macro do a find and replace function on all sheets except the sheet holding the table containing the find and replace values. However, when the macro is executed it replaces the values in the table and does not replace the values in the rest of the worksheets.

I pulled this code from a website:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/14/find-and-replace-all

since they were trying to achieve my same goal but it does not work. Mine is modified a bit because initially my data had been formatted differently but I changed it to match the website input, and despite that it still doesn't work.

I've tried using the methods Worksheets.Count and cycling using i = 2 to ws_count and placing the find & replace table as the first sheet, however this also failed. I also tried a select case method but that failed as well.

I'm wondering if some background setting is changed and that's preventing it from recognizing the sheet name? Unsure what the problem is as my formatting seems to be exactly the same as resolved questions that are asking basically the same thing.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindList As Long, ReplaceList As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim ReplaceArray As Variant
Dim j As Long


'Variable pointing to table
  Set tbl = Worksheets("DataSheet").ListObjects("ReplaceTable")

'Code here loads table data into array

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For i = LBound(ReplaceArray, 1) To UBound(ReplaceArray, 2)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook except data sheet
      For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "DataSheet" Then

            ws.Cells.Replace What:=ReplaceArray(FindList, i), Replacement:=ReplaceArray(ReplaceList, i), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        End If
      Next ws
  Next i
```

Ideal output being values defined in find list within table are replaced with values in the replace list on all sheets except the sheet containing the table.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the worksheet containing the find/replace table is named `"DataSheet"`?  Is there any possibility of whitespace before or after the sheet name such that it's actually `" DataSheet"` or `"DataSheet "`?  That would cause the problem.  Can find out by doing `MsgBox "x" & ws.Name & "x"` to check if whitespace exists, and then correct as appropriate.  Could also use the codename instead which might be more reliable.

Comment: Maybe try using `For Each ws In Application.Workbooks("WorkbookName").Worksheets`  instead of `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` @busterScruggs and tell me if it solved your issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I confirmed that there was no whitespace using the message box method so we're able to rule that out as an issue. The codename and Application.Workbooks ideas both worked in that the sheets had the target values replaced, however, the sheet containing the reference replace data was also replaced, so it's still not skipping that sheet. It also began producing this result with the ActiveWorkbook syntax, and this macro is intended to be applied to multiple workbooks which is why I was trying to avoid hardcoding it into the macro. Again, thank you!!

Comment: I checked the macro again this morning, and after copy & pasting the code into a new workbook it executed as intended. I don't know what I was doing wrong in the original workbook or if it was excel just being finnicky, but now it works 100%!